# Film about a guy who travels back in time through a cave, brings an old man to the present and tells him the "strange bird" he's seeing is a plane

Tags: story-identification, movie, time-travel

It was sometime between 2007-2014 I saw this (colored) film, and I only remember very few details.

It was about a young guy (between 15-25), who went into a cave. Inside, there was a shape of a hand craved into the wall of the cave. He put his hand there, and that made him travel back in time.

I don't know how far he went back, but I know that he found an old man, with grey hair. He brought him back to the present. I remember there was a scene when the old man looked up at the sky, and saw a strange bird. The young guy told him it was a plane.

I have already read Wikipedia's [List of time travel works of fiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_time_travel_works_of_fiction), without success.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! This question would be improved by going through the checklists here; [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*Escape to Grizzly Mountain* (2000), most likely.

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0198460/):

> Jimmy, a young boy trying to gain acceptance from his peers, is horrified when he sees a circus trainer abusing a bear cub. One of the circus employees tells Jimmy that **there is a magic cave in the hills nearby that can transport people to another time**, and that maybe he can use it to help the bear. Jimmy does some exploring, finds the cave, and is amazed to find himself transported back to the early 1800's where he encounters Jeremiah, a nature-loving mountain man with a bear friend of his own. **Jeremiah agrees to come to the future and help out Jimmy, but the 21st century is quite different from the 19th**, and springing the bear cub will not be as easy as Jeremiah thinks. Not in any way related to the "Grizzly Adams" television series.

It's on YouTube, relevant timestamps:

- boy places his hand on the hand print at 30'08
- the "strange bird", "like an eagle with no feathers" scene takes place at 52'20

---

Found with the Google query `movie time travel "a * cave" "back in time" site:imdb.com/title` which returned [*Grizzly Mountain*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113223/) (1996), upon searching for the movie on YouTube, it came clear that its sequel *Escape to Grizzly Mountain* was a better fit.

Comment: Wow, that was quick! Thank you very much!

Comment: @AstroRP you're welcome, enjoy the re-watch! :)